# HibernateSearch querying on virtual fields indexed via FieldBridge

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate Search in version 5.0.0.Final.
I have 1 field indexed in 1 table. I'm using a FieldBridge to index that field :

```
public class CustomBridge implements FieldBridge {

    @Override
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        MyFieldType file = (ProductOrderJsonEntity) value;
        if (file.getA() != null && file.getB() != null) {
            luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument(name + ".ABconcat", file.getA() + file.getB(), document);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using FieldBridge to index a field that does not exist in the DB, so when I try to make query like this, it crashes :

```
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
em.getTransaction().begin();

QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(MyEntity.class).get();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword().onFields("productOrder.internalReference", "techId").matching(keyword).createQuery();

javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, MyEntity.class);
```

... with the following error :

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Unable to find field field.ABconcat in com.something.myapp.MyEntity
```

Apparently it tries to map the fields I give in the luceneQuery to the Object fields (MyEntity in my case).

Is there any way to query the index on custom fields that does not exist in the database ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out about [this post](http://in.relation.to/2015/07/24/hibernate-search-complex-type-query/) which explains that you can query field that have been indexed through FieldBridge like this :

Query targeting multiple fields

```
int year = datetime.getYear();
int month = datetime.getMonthOfYear();
int day = datetime.getDayOfMonth();

QueryBuilder qb = sm.buildQueryBuilderForClass(BlogEntry.class).get();
Query q = qb.bool()
    .must( qb.keyword().onField("creationdate.year").ignoreFieldBridge().ignoreAnalyzer()
                .matching(year).createQuery() )
    .must( qb.keyword().onField("creationdate.month").ignoreFieldBridge().ignoreAnalyzer()
                .matching(month).createQuery() )
    .must( qb.keyword().onField("creationdate.day").ignoreFieldBridge().ignoreAnalyzer()
                .matching(day).createQuery() )
   .createQuery();

CacheQuery cq = sm.getQuery(q, BlogEntry.class);
System.out.println(cq.getResultSize());
```

> The key is to:
>
> target directly each field,
>
> disable the field bridge conversion for the query,
>
> and it’s probably a good idea to disable the analyzer.
>
> It’s a rather advanced topic and the query DSL will do the right thing
>   most of the time. No need to panic just yet.
>
> But in case you hit a complex type needs, it’s interesting to
>   understand what is going on underneath.

Comment: Your answer is correct, on top of this - assuming you could upgrade to Hibernate Search 5.5.3 - you could declare the fields which you're creating in the FieldBridge by using a `org.hibernate.search.bridge.MetadataProvidingFieldBridge`. That should improve the DSL integration. See also https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2021